# Question on integer values of Riemann's prime-power counting function

Tags: number-theory, summation, prime-numbers

Is it known whether Riemann's prime-power counting function

$$\Pi(x)=\sum\limits_{p^n\le x} \frac{1}{n}=\sum\limits_{n=2}^x \frac{\Lambda(n)}{\log(n)}=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\log_2(x)} \frac{1}{n}\, \pi\left(x^{1/n}\right)$$

ever takes on an integer value for $x\ge 4$?

---

I tested for integer values in the range $4\le x\le 10,000,000$ and couldn't seem to find an example.

---

I also searched the Internet and couldn't seem to find any information related to this question.

---

Noting that only proper prime-powers $p^n$ (proper meaning $n>1$) affect the non-integer portion of $\Pi(x)$, the following table illustrates the individual contribution of each proper prime-power $p^n$ and the accumulated non-integer portion of $\Pi(p^n)$ for $p^n\le 10,000$.

---

$$\begin{array}{ccc}
 p^n & \frac{1}{n} & \Pi \left(p^n\right)-\left\lfloor \Pi \left(p^n\right)\right\rfloor  \\
 4=2^2 & \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2} \\
 8=2^3 & \frac{1}{3} & \frac{5}{6} \\
 9=3^2 & \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{3} \\
 16=2^4 & \frac{1}{4} & \frac{7}{12} \\
 25=5^2 & \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{12} \\
 27=3^3 & \frac{1}{3} & \frac{5}{12} \\
 32=2^5 & \frac{1}{5} & \frac{37}{60} \\
 49=7^2 & \frac{1}{2} & \frac{7}{60} \\
 64=2^6 & \frac{1}{6} & \frac{17}{60} \\
 81=3^4 & \frac{1}{4} & \frac{8}{15} \\
 121=11^2 & \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{30} \\
 125=5^3 & \frac{1}{3} & \frac{11}{30} \\
 128=2^7 & \frac{1}{7} & \frac{107}{210} \\
 169=13^2 & \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{105} \\
 243=3^5 & \frac{1}{5} & \frac{22}{105} \\
 256=2^8 & \frac{1}{8} & \frac{281}{840} \\
 289=17^2 & \frac{1}{2} & \frac{701}{840} \\
 343=7^3 & \frac{1}{3} & \frac{47}{280} \\
 361=19^2 & \frac{1}{2} & \frac{187}{280} \\
 512=2^9 & \frac{1}{9} & \frac{1963}{2520} \\
 529=23^2 & \frac{1}{2} & \frac{703}{2520} \\
 625=5^4 & \frac{1}{4} & \frac{1333}{2520} \\
 729=3^6 & \frac{1}{6} & \frac{1753}{2520} \\
 841=29^2 & \frac{1}{2} & \frac{493}{2520} \\
 961=31^2 & \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1753}{2520} \\
 1024=2^{10} & \frac{1}{10} & \frac{401}{504} \\
 1331=11^3 & \frac{1}{3} & \frac{65}{504} \\
 1369=37^2 & \frac{1}{2} & \frac{317}{504} \\
 1681=41^2 & \frac{1}{2} & \frac{65}{504} \\
 1849=43^2 & \frac{1}{2} & \frac{317}{504} \\
 2048=2^{11} & \frac{1}{11} & \frac{3991}{5544} \\
 2187=3^7 & \frac{1}{7} & \frac{4783}{5544} \\
 2197=13^3 & \frac{1}{3} & \frac{1087}{5544} \\
 2209=47^2 & \frac{1}{2} & \frac{3859}{5544} \\
 2401=7^4 & \frac{1}{4} & \frac{5245}{5544} \\
 2809=53^2 & \frac{1}{2} & \frac{2473}{5544} \\
 3125=5^5 & \frac{1}{5} & \frac{17909}{27720} \\
 3481=59^2 & \frac{1}{2} & \frac{4049}{27720} \\
 3721=61^2 & \frac{1}{2} & \frac{17909}{27720} \\
 4096=2^{12} & \frac{1}{12} & \frac{20219}{27720} \\
 4489=67^2 & \frac{1}{2} & \frac{6359}{27720} \\
 4913=17^3 & \frac{1}{3} & \frac{15599}{27720} \\
 5041=71^2 & \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1739}{27720} \\
 5329=73^2 & \frac{1}{2} & \frac{15599}{27720} \\
 6241=79^2 & \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1739}{27720} \\
 6561=3^8 & \frac{1}{8} & \frac{1301}{6930} \\
 6859=19^3 & \frac{1}{3} & \frac{3611}{6930} \\
 6889=83^2 & \frac{1}{2} & \frac{73}{3465} \\
 7921=89^2 & \frac{1}{2} & \frac{3611}{6930} \\
 8192=2^{13} & \frac{1}{13} & \frac{53873}{90090} \\
 9409=97^2 & \frac{1}{2} & \frac{4414}{45045} \\
\end{array}$$

Comment: @Peter No, see [here](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/RiemannPrimeCountingFunction.html) for example.

Answer (score 1):

Claim : We always have $2^q<3^p$ , if $p\ge 5$ is a prime and $q$ the next prime after $p$.

It is sufficient to show $\frac{q}{p}<log_2(3)$ , which holds for $5\le p\le 10^7$ and the prime number theorem should easily prove that this more than enough to show it for all $p\ge 5$.

You have shown that upto $n=32$ , the sum is never an integer. This is the first time , we have a summand with a denominator divisible by $5$.

To get an integer , we have to compensate this and need another $5$ th power , the next is $3^5$. But before, we arrive at $2^7$ giving the first denominator divisble by $7$.

Before we can even begin to compensate it with $3^7$ , we arrive at $2^{11}$ and so on. So the sum can never be an integer.

This can surely be summarized more elegant , but I think you get the idea behind this proof.

Comment: Upto $10^{10}$ , the smallest fractional part occurs here : $$21253933\   2871887/5354228880 \ \   0.00053637733170644733439187605293406881777$$

Comment: Thanks for taking a look at my question. Does your argument account for the addition of $\frac{1}{n}$ when $n\notin\mathbb{P}$, or do these contributions not help cancel out factors of $p$ in the denominator where $p|n$?